# Passing Javascript variable from one function to another function for use in a sqlite query

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am trying to write a Javascript function that obtains an array of unique ids from an sqlite database & then passes them to be used in another function where the ids can be used in another sql query, they also form part of a dynamically created list.

I have managed to pass the ids row['id'] to the array variable window.symp[i].  But I have not been able to access them correctly in the second function below, the second function correctly uses the ids to create the dynamic html but the variable passed to the sqlite query either fails or is the same value in all the list items created.  Any help would be greatly appreciated - I have included both functions below:

```
function showContent() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT id, notes FROM webkit WHERE notes LIKE 'A%'", [], function (tx, result) {
            var notesanode = document.getElementById('notesa');
            notesanode.innerHTML = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; ++i) {
                var row = result.rows.item(i);
                window.symp[i] = i;
                window.symp[i] = row['id'];
                var noteadiv = document.createElement('div');
                noteadiv.innerHTML = '<li class=\"arrow\"><a id=\"0\" onClick=\"showSymptoms()\" href=\"#symptoms\">' + row['notes'] + " " + row['id'] + '</a></li>';
                notesanode.appendChild(noteadiv);

            }

        }, function (tx, error) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve notes from database - ' + error.message);
            return;
        });
    });
}

function showSymptoms() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT sid, symptom FROM slinks WHERE id LIKE ('" + symp + "')", [], function (tx, result) {
            var symptomnode = document.getElementById('symptomid');
            symptomnode.innerHTML = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; ++i) {
                var row = result.rows.item(i);
                var symptomdiv = document.createElement('div');
                symptomdiv.innerHTML = '<p><label> <input type=checkbox>' + row['symptom'] + '</label></p>';
                symptomnode.appendChild(symptomdiv);
            }

        }, function (tx, error) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve notes from database - ' + error.message);
            return;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two things:

The main issue is that you need

```
"SELECT sid, symptom FROM slinks WHERE id LIKE ('" + window.symp.join(',') + "')"
```

instead of what you have up there.

The second issue is that you have

```
window.symp[i] = i;
window.symp[i] = row['id'];
```

you can just go ahead and remove `window.symp[i] = i;` because it gets immediately overwritten by the line that follows it.

Comment: Hi sorry but that does not work, nothing is dynamically created because the variable window.symp does hold all the correct ids when I test it, but for some reason I still cannot access them individually in the second function select statement. As suggested I have removed window.symp[i] = i; and that is fine. Any further input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `window.symp.join(',')` in your select statement?

Comment: When I add window.symp.join(',') to the select statement, the page loads with no results and when I test the variable symp it holds exactly the same array as previously.

Comment: I am sorry I did not explain very well previously, the ids in the array are correct, I just cannot figure out how to update the variable symp with the correct array index value (based on the dynamically created list item selected in the first function).  So for instance the first function creates a list of 6 items with ids 1 to 6, the user then selects one of the list items which should then give them a set of check boxes that are dynamically created based on the id attached to the list item they have chosen.
I cannot tell you how grateful I am for you help.

Comment: I just noticed something else, I think the SQL construct you want is `IN` not `LIKE`.  Try that with the `join(',')` function.